Text box overflows into sidebar
The text box now covers part of the sidebar. This wasnt happening before, so its probably because of some recent change. 

My browser is Chromium Version 25.0.1364.160 on Ubuntu 12.04.
This behavior is observed on multiple sites.
UPDATE :
Still present on Chromium Version 28.0.1500.71 Ubuntu 12.04.

which os/browser are you using?

@m0sa Edited. .

couldn't reproduce it on a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (x64) and Chromium (via Ubuntu Software Center -> version 28.0.1500.52-0ubuntu1.12.04.2)

@m0sa That Chromium update came out recently. Thanks for checking this out!

@m0sa Its still here. See update.
